# Multi-select same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `company_Id_Company` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `head_Id_Head` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `detail_Id_Detail` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`company_Id_Company`,`head_Id_Head`),
  KEY `fk_test1_detail` (`id`,`head_Id_Head`,`detail_Id_Detail`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test1_detail` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `head_Id_Head`, `detail_Id_Detail`) REFERENCES `detail` (`id`, `head_Id_Head`, `id_Detail`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test1_company` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `company_Id_Company`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`, `id_Company`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and I have this data in the table:

```
 id | company_Id_Company | head_Id_Head | detail_Id_Detail
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1            01                1                7
 1            02                1                7
 1            01                3                2
 1            03                2                9
 1            05                4                1
 1            01                5                4
 1            02                5                4
 1            03                5                4
```

**I need to find all data that meets the two mandatory conditions simultaneously:**

```
select * from test1 where head_Id_Head = 1 and detail_Id_Detail = 7
                 AND
select * from test1 where head_Id_Head = 5 and detail_Id_Detail = 4
```

If the two queries are running, I should be compañoa: 01 and 02

How I could make this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would assume you dont have duplicates..

```
SELECT  *
FROM    test1 t1
WHERE   [company_Id_Company] IN (SELECT [company_Id_Company]
                                 FROM   test1 t2
                                 WHERE  ((t2.head_Id_Head = 1
                                              AND t2.detail_Id_Detail = 7)
                                             OR (t2.head_Id_Head = 5
                                                 AND t2.detail_Id_Detail = 4))
                                 GROUP BY t2.[company_Id_Company]
                                 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do by `OR` not `AND`:

```
select your_table.company_Id_Company from your_table  inner join (
select company_Id_Company from your_table where  head_Id_Head = 5 
AND   detail_Id_Detail = 4) as temp on temp.company_Id_Company your_table.company_Id_Company  
where head_Id_Head = 1 AND detail_Id_Detail = 7
```

Comment: No, because this query give me "01, 02 and 03". I need all data that meets the two mandatory conditions

Comment: how, give me example?

Comment: I dont know how make this query. the company 01 and 02 are the only two that meet two requirements (head_Id_Head = 1 AND detail_Id_Detail = 7) AND (head_Id_Head = 5 AND detail_Id_Detail = 4)

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly INNER JOIN the two result sets

```
select 
from test1 AS T1
   INNER JOIN (select * from test1 where head_Id_Head = 5 and detail_Id_Detail = 4) AS T2 
   ON T2.company_Id_Company = T1.company_Id_Company 
where T1.head_Id_Head = 1 and T1.detail_Id_Detail = 7
```

Or even simpler

```
select * 
from test1 
where head_Id_Head = 1 and detail_Id_Detail = 7
AND company_Id_Company IN (select company_Id_Company from test1 where head_Id_Head = 5 and detail_Id_Detail = 4)
```